# Pandas merge based on str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've got two dataframes as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'metro':['Santa Maria-Santa Barbara', 
     'New York', 'Los Angeles'], 
     'state':['California', 'New York', 'California']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'metro':['Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim', 
      'New York-Newark-Jersey City', 'Jefferson'], 
      'state':['California', 'New York-New Jersey-Pennsylvania', 'Georgia']})
```

I'd like to merge (left join, df1 is left, and df2 is right) based on this condition:

```
*pseudo-code*
df2['metro'].str.contains(df1['metro']) & df2['state'].str.contains(df1['state'])
```

Edit:
To further clarify based on John's comment below —
I want 'New York-New Jersey-Pennsylvania' in `df2['metro']` to match 'New York' in `df1['metro']` (**and** similarly with `state`).

Pandas merge function doesn't allow this kind of conditional match. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You say `df2['metro'].str.contains(df1['metro'])` but that doesn't actually run....would you expect 'New York-Newark-Jersey City' in df2 to match with 'New York' in df1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It was pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is clean (prepare) your data:

```
def clean(df):
    parts = [df[col].str.split('-', expand=True) for col in df.columns]
    return pd.concat(parts, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
```

That gives you:

```
         metro                      state
             0              1           0
0  Santa Maria  Santa Barbara  California
1     New York           None    New York
2  Los Angeles           None  California
```

and:

```
         metro                                state                          
             0           1            2           0           1             2
0  Los Angeles  Long Beach      Anaheim  California        None          None
1     New York      Newark  Jersey City    New York  New Jersey  Pennsylvania
2    Jefferson        None         None     Georgia        None          None
```

Now you'll probably need to do more normalization, but you'll have to figure out how.  For example it's not clear when you have `New York-Newark-Jersey City` and `New York-New Jersey-Pennsylvania`...you might need to map NYC to NYS and Newark/JC to NJ and nothing to PA.

Here's one example of what you can do with the cleaned data so far:

```
df1a = clean(df1)
df2a = clean(df2)
df1a.metro[0].isin(df2a.metro[0])
```

That gives you `[False, True, True]`.  You can repeat for each column in the metro sections of each DataFrame.

So I realize this is not a full solution to your entire problem, but hopefully it gets you on the right track.  Clean the data, normalize the data, then process the data.